# How to quickly duplicate faces or other elements?

Tags: modeling

Lets say I'm making a building and so I have rows of identical windows. Is it possible to make one window, and then quickly duplicate it to create a perfectly-alligned row of identical windows?

Comment: have you tried the Array modifier?

Comment: Hmm, that's actually an interesting idea, so I can have the main block of the building, and then make a window as a separate object that I can then duplicate via Array.


I was also thinking about maybe creating a cube with one window and then turning it into a row of windows through Array or maybe Mirror, and then stacking those rows to form a single building. 


Thanks a lot for the tip.

Comment: actually I think you can make the whole building, and not only the windows, with arrays

Comment: A different approach would be dupliverts.

Comment: @moonboots


Yeah, I've just did a quick test and I can just make an entire building with array, thanks a lot!

Comment: @cegaton


While it seems like I've found a solution, can you explain a bit more about your approach? I'm just learning, so new info is always nice.